# Tableview works on sim but not on test device

Tags: swift, uitableview, ios-simulator

I have no idea whats wrong with this function. I'm calling it in viewdidload and it prints the array as blank when I load it on my phone. When I do it in the simulator it fills the array though. Using ObjectMapper if that helps at all.

```
func getData() {

    let myURLString = "http://meetup.x10host.com/api/get_event.php?radius=15"
    let myURL = NSURL(string: myURLString)!


    var myCardsArray = [Card]()


    let mySession = NSURLSession(configuration: NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration())

    let myDataTask = mySession.dataTaskWithURL(myURL) { (data, response, error) in
        guard error == nil else {
            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "No Connection", message:
                "Can't connect to database, perhaps turn on your WiFi?", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
            alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Okay", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default,handler: nil))
            self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            return
        }
        do {
            let jsonData = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments)
            for someCard in jsonData as! NSArray{
                let card = Mapper<Card>().map(someCard)
                myCardsArray.append(card!)

                self.nameArray.append(card!.titlee!)
                self.textArray.append(card!.text!)
                self.userArray.append(card!.attending!)
                self.latArray.append(card!.latitude!)
                self.longArray.append(card!.longitude!)
                self.timeArray.append(card!.time!)
                self.locTextArray.append(card!.locationText!)


                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
        } catch {
            print("There was an error")
        }
    }
    myDataTask.resume()

  print(nameArray)
}
```

Comment: Did you try setting some breakpoints? Are you getting any errors? Is data being fetched?

Comment: Yea its something with the above  function, it works on the simulator but not on the device

Comment: Is the response correctly serialized into JSON, are then into objects?